# Communicating with fragments using FragmentTransaction

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I want two fragments to communicate with each other. ProductDisplayFragment will "send" the object to PaymentFragment. The following code shows the code where I used FragmentTransaction to send object over to PaymentFragment.

This code works except when I try to send over the FIRST object. First object is never received. When I try to add "paymentFragment.getProduct(product);" in else statement, the app will crash.

Here is my code:

Under ProductDisplayFragment.java:

```
@Override
    public void onProductSelected(Product product) {
        PaymentFragment paymentFragment = (PaymentFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_payment_list);
        if(paymentFragment != null) {
            paymentFragment.getProduct(product);
        } else {
            paymentFragment = new PaymentFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putSerializable(KEY_PRODUCT, product);
            paymentFragment.setArguments(args);

            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_payment_list, paymentFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }
```

Under ProductFragment.java

```
public void getProduct(Product product) {
     // Do something to product item
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that for the first product I just have to use getArguments for Bundle in onCreateView method as shown below:

```
    // Get first product
    Bundle arguments = getArguments();
    if (arguments != null) {
        Product product = (Product) arguments.getSerializable(KEY_PRODUCT);
        getProduct(product);
    }
```